# Unrecognized Selector (NSMutableArray+NSString)

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsmutablearray, unrecognized-selector

A very basic yet puzzling error;

```
NSString *selectedCategory = @"Rock";

if (self.quoteOpt.selectedSegmentIndex == 1) 
{
        selectedCategory = @"Programming";
}

//filter array by ti tle using predicate
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"Genre == %@", selectedCategory];
NSArray *filteredArray = [self.movieQuotes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];

int array_tot = [filteredArray count];

if(array_tot > 0)
{
   int index = (arc4random() % array_tot);
   NSMutableArray *a = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:index];
   NSString *s = [a objectAtIndex:1];
   self.quoteText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Genre \n\n %@",s];
}
else
{
   self.quoteText.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"No quotes to display."];
}
```

I'm puzzled by the way it behaves, the error churned out comes from

```
NSString *s = [a objectAtIndex:1];
```

I did a po hexaddress, it appears to be int but where did it came from?

po'ing both *a and *s results to respectively;

*a:

```
(NSMutableArray *) $3 = 0x088941f0 {
  Genre = Rock;
  Name = Creed;
  "New item" = Higher;
 }
```

*s:

```
(int) $4 = 143213040 {
  Genre = Rock;
  Name = Creed;
  "New item" = Higher;
}
```

I can't figure it out, I've been looking, but the error is very generic/vague in nature that no specific answer can be acquired. (my two cents tho)

TIA

Comment: What is the output if you NSLog your filteredArray?

Comment: (NSArray *) $2 = 0x06a6c1c0 <__NSArrayI 0x6a6c1c0>(
{
    Genre = Rock;
    Name = Warrant;
    Title = Heaven;
},
{
    Genre = Rock;
    Name = Creed;
    "New item" = Higher;
}
)

Comment: Hmm, and you are sure that it is a NSString you have at index 1?

As geraldWilliam says, it look like NSDIctionaries in your array, not strings..

Comment: self.movieQuotes is an NSDictionary from a PropList, however, I seem to be confused, did you mean this line of code **NSArray *filteredArray = [self.movieQuotes filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];** does not implicitly says that its an array?

Comment: Well it is an array - the NSLog proves that. Just not sure that it is containing strings. Try use id instead of NSString and set a breakpoint - then see what type it is when you take it out of the array.

Meaning id s = [a objectAtIndex :1]

Comment: it was really tricky... finding out that, it doesn't mean that a value will be automatically typed-cast into another type when passed/assigned to another type, it seems to maintain its original type (how true is this?), the initial guess that it was an NSDictionary was correct in the first place, it's just confusing seeing the values being passed around and getting assumed to have changed its type. Did I forgot to learn something here?

Comment: I was just too stubborn to insist that its an array... what a deceitful eyes.. NSMutableArray *a = [filteredArray objectAtIndex:index]; id s = a; NSLog(@"%@",[s class]); = __NSCFDictionary